# Parameter casting in reflections in C# VS2010

Tags: c#, string, parameters, casting, system.reflection

Can i pass strings as arguments during **method.Invoke(objectname,object[]params)** for a method of signature **Getdetails(int,string,bool)** without casting them to respective types before passing?

---

Will reflection handle the casting or should i be dynamically cast this to appropriate param types matching the function signature? I am calling couple of methods with different signatures in the same application.

---

### So,here is the scenario:

I store the methodId with parameter types and values in a table.and then retrieve them and call using reflections. But i get a *TargetInvocationException* or *Cannot convert System.String to System.Int32.*

Comment: No, reflection won't do the casting for you.  As you found out.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Should i create separate calls for calling methods with return types and the ones with void as the return type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not handle. You have to create and pass an object array:

```
method.Invoke(object,new object[]{1, "test", true});
```

Answer (score 0):

You already answered your own question. You can't do this. The parameters you pass must be of the correct type.